# Shiny Select Input indirectly and show group

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I've got a flexdashboard in combination with shiny and there is the following problem:

In my case, I want to select an application field and it should show all the spots belonging to this with their sales potential in a plotly. 
Now, I don't know how to link the select input with the plot, because the plots aes are x = spot and y = sales potential, so the application field is only indirectly representedy in the plot.

```
selectInput("af", "Anwendungsfeld auswählen", data_summwwafspot$af)


renderPlotly({ 
  plot_ly(data_summwwafspot,
    x = ~spot,
    y = ~get(input$af),
    name = "Potential world wide per spot and AF",
    color = "red",
    type = 'bar'  
    ) %>% 
    layout(xaxis = list(title="Klebestellen", showline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE)) %>% 
    layout(yaxis = list(title="Potential in Mio. €", range=c(0, 200000000))) 
})
```

I hope, the description is understandable. Any help is much appreciated and many thanks in advance.

Now some example data:

**Name,**             **Fruit,**           **ValueFruit**

Anton,            Apple,           1,5

Florian,          Banana,          0,3

Anton,            Apricots,        0,1

Christopher,      Cherries,        1,2

Tom,              Orange,          0,85

Florian,          Grapefruit,      2,0

Anton,            Lemon,           1,8

So I would like to display fruits and value fruits in a bar plot, x = fruit, y = valueFruit.
The select input should include the names and if I select e.g. Anton, I'd like to see all the fruits (and values) of Anton in the plot.

Comment: Providing some more details like example data, and a reprex (an actual functioning minimal shiny app) would help.   It's likely that what you want is to have the selectInput modify the data that is then fed into plotly.

Comment: @TTS 
I edited the question post and add some example data.

Comment: Hi @Andey96, that's not a reprex and your data cannot be directly copied and pasted in R. To include some example data, create manually the code to generate a fake data frame and paste it here, or use an existing dataframe (like ```mtcars```) or use ```dput``` on a sample of your data to automatically generate the code to reproduce it. Moreover, you haven't put a fully reproducible example, just the part that you're in trouble with. That makes it hard for people to help you, so please include a fully [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)